# Mongo DB Authentication Failed With Spring (REST)

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, authentication

Still now I'm using mongodb version 2.6.9 with spring (REST). In the authentication part, I have edited the mongod.conf file and enabled

> auth = true

And added the below codes in spring - applicationContext.xml file

```
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" id="mongo" />
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory"
        mongo-ref="mongo"
        host="localhost"
        port="27017"
        dbname="********"
        username="******"
        password="********"   
        />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Start @@ Bean mapping for Restlet service -->
<bean id="basecampComponent" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
    <property name="defaultTarget" ref="autoRestletAppliction" />
</bean>

<bean id="autoRestletAppliction" class="com.jiit.restlet.frontcontroller.FirstStepsApplication">
    <property name="inboundRoot" ref="router" />
</bean>

<bean name="router" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringBeanRouter" />
```

And the jar's i have used, for the above configuration,

```
mongo-java-driver-2.12.1.jar & 
spring-data-mongodb-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Now, I want to upgrade my mongodb to 3.4 Version. And I have tried to edit the `mongod.conf` file and enabled the security,

```
security.authorization: enabled
```

And I have added admin and mydb with users and tried to connect with mongodb client like robomongo and its works fine.

The problem is i'm not able to connect with spring to mongodb.

I have updated the jars to latest version but its not working. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of problem a few days back. But then I stumbled upon this http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/ and it solved all my problems of mongodb connectivity through spring.

*They have provided a proper explanations and how you could connect to your mongodb with or without credentials.*

Comment: Thank you. the above mentioned article looks good for a stand alone program. They did'nt mentioned how to configure in spring - applicationContext.xml

Comment: So you need it implemented in the applictionContext?

Comment: Yes. I wants to implemented in the applicationContext.